# Consecutive Square Numbers

Tags: square-numbers, word-problem

The difference between the squares of two consecutive numbers is $23$. What are the two numbers?

Comment: **Hint:** Call the two consecutive numbers $a$ and $a+1$, so $(a+1)^2 - (a)^2 = 23$

Answer (score 1):

$a^2-(a+1)^2=2a+1=23$ for some $a \in \textbf{Z}$. Therefore $a=11$.

Comment: Nitpick:  (a+1)^2 > a^2.

Answer (score 1):

Let the two numbers be $n$ and $n-1$. The difference of their squares is 
$$n^2-(n-1)^2 = (n+(n-1))(n-(n-1)) = (2n-1)(1)=2n-1$$ using the difference of two squares factorisation, and this is equal to 23, so:
$$2n-1=23$$ giving 
$$n=12$$
so the numbers are 11 and 12.

Check: $12^2-11^2 = 144-121=23$